# Android AAR third party jars

Tags: android, jar, gradle, dependencies, aar

I have made an AAR using Android Studio and I can successfully use it in any app. Problem is I have to add all the dependencies it needs manually to the app build.gradle (like   compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.7.10').

I want the AAR to actually include all these third-party dependencies it requires so I won't have to add them manually in the app. Is there a way you would know of?

Comment: Have you found your solution yet?What I know that it's not possible,though I don't have a lot idea about  AAR

Comment: You are right. It's apparently not doable with AAR. AAR is basically a zip of all the jars and android dependencies in one place.

Comment: No no no, You can see Rosie(https://github.com/Karumi/Rosie). This library can include third-party library in arr with 'compile 'com.karumi.rosie:rosie:2.0.0''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use
`compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`
and put a jar in libs folder, this jar will be included in the AAR.

But you have to put the jar yourself. 
As far as I know, there is no way to put a repository dependency inside an AAR.